# bash script which to use Google password manager API to log in a website

Tags: scripts, google

I want to write a bash script which opens a link in my browser. In order to open the link it should use Google password manager API to get the user and Password and automatically sign in and open the targeted link. is it possible to do such a thing?

Comment: I'd be surprised if anyone could pull that off. In order to retrieve the username/password-combination for a website stored in the Google Password manager, you would need to be logged in to Google. In order for your script to do that, you need to set up a complete OAuth2 exchange between your script and Google. At that point it is far easier to store the username/password in the script itself and use something like Basic Authentication.

Comment: Even if you could it would be way easier to do in a "real" programming language, like c/c++, python or Java. The needed libraries to do this kind of operation are already in place.